# PCAP_OPENFLAG_NOCAPTURE_LOCAL not working on windows 10

Tags: winpcap, npcap

I want to bridge two adapters on Windows 10 using WinPcap/npcap library. Even after setting the flag PCAP_OPENFLAG_NOCAPTURE_LOCAL, I'm still receiving packets indefinitely (packets sent by Adapter A are sent to Adapter B and vice versa, in a loop).
I'm using the example code provided here https://github.com/nmap/npcap/tree/master/Examples/UserLevelBridge. Does anyone know a solution to this problem?